# AttributeError: 'RetrievalQA' object has no attribute 'llm'. Does anyone have solution for this?

Tags: openai-api, large-language-model, llama

LLM: LlamaCpp
Params: {'model_path': './models/models--TheBloke--Llama-2-7b-Chat-GGUF/snapshots/191239b3e26b2882fb562ffccdd1cf0f65402adb/llama-2-7b-chat.Q4_K_M.gguf', 'suffix': None, 'max_tokens': 4096, 'temperature': 0.8, 'top_p': 0.95, 'logprobs': None, 'echo': False, 'stop_sequences': [], 'repeat_penalty': 1.1, 'top_k': 40}
Retriever: tags=['Chroma', 'HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings'] vectorstore=<langchain.vectorstores.chroma.Chroma object at 0x7f6a2ccafe50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jennil/localGPT/localGPT/run_localGPT.py", line 283, in 
main()
File "/home/jennil/anaconda3/envs/localgpt_history/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in **call**
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jennil/anaconda3/envs/localgpt_history/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/home/jennil/anaconda3/envs/localgpt_history/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/home/jennil/anaconda3/envs/localgpt_history/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jennil/localGPT/localGPT/run_localGPT.py", line 251, in main
print("RetrievalQA llm:", qa.llm)
AttributeError: 'RetrievalQA' object has no attribute 'llm'

I have tried upgrading the langchain, but it is still not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.